# Wait replacement before NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, replacement, syntax

To pose my question more concretely, let me consider the minimal example

```
NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}] /. a -> 0.241
```

which gives as output:

[image]

```
0.241
```

1. why the result is correct despite the warning?
2. how do I perform the replacement correctly, without getting warnings?

For 2), of course I would avoid using "Quiet", but rather knowing how to make Mathematica wait the replacement before evaluating.

Comment: ``NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a} /. a -> 0.241]``

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility, but my case is more complex, as I have a function f, and want to do $f/.a->0.241$

Comment: ``NIntegrate[1 /. a -> 0.241, {u, 0, a} /. a -> 0.241]`` or ``Hold@NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}] /. a -> 0.241 // ReleaseHold`` or ``With[{a = 0.241}, NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}]]``.

Comment: Or define your function using explicit arguments, i.e., `f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}]`

Comment: "1. why...": Because `NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}]` evaluates to `NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}]` with an error message; next `a` is replaced by `0.241`; next because of the change in `a`, the new `NIntegrate` code evaluates to the numeric result. Note that the error message does not cause the evaluation to abort. "2. how...": `Unevaluated@NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}] /. a -> 0.241` or `Block[{NIntegrate}, NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}] /. a -> 0.241]` or `Hold@NIntegrate[1, {u, 0, a}] /. Hold[code_] :> Block[{a = 0.241}, code]` or...